# In a world where short-term space travel is common, what reason the government would have for banning long-term exploration?

Tags: science-fiction, government, space-travel

In a sci-fi world where a planet has developed short space travels between the planet and its moons, what would be a good reason for the current form of government to not only disencourage, but straight up forbid long explorative voyages to other planets?

The long-term travel system would've existed before, but it has been so much time since these travels were attempted that any contact to other civilizations would've been lost and forgotten by the majorities. Any attempt to leave the planetary rim would be botched by the government, with the perpetrators either arrested or killed in the process.

I was considering maybe a war with alien species could've caused this particular part of the universe to be exiled for the rest, but considering nobody even *knows* that long-term travels can be executed, maybe there could be another more dubious reason why people are left in the dark about this.

Comment: Do you want the reason and public explanation to be the same, or the government can keep secrets from the public?

Comment: it can, and would be best if it did

Comment: @Hizome In the future you may want to hold of on accepting an answer for a while. In some cases you may get another answer that better answers your question. Accepting an answer early may limit future answers as users can view the question as resolved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The government could view such voyages to be a waste of resources and, were such voyages to be encouraged, a continuing loss of skills, especially amongst those most likely to participate.

However, depending upon the government, and other factors, there could be a fear of a mass exodus.

Perhaps the fear is not of voyages going out, but of coming back with news that the government does not want to become public, for some reason?

A possible reason: Out there, on other planets is an alien race who are actually controlling the government and in the process of preparing the population for something rather unpleasant - maybe as hosts for a parasitic lifeform, sacrifices to a god, or food.

Answer (score 4):

Look at this example of the [Ming Dynasty](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/663/why-did-china-shut-itself-out-of-the-world-in-the-15th-century) over on Stack Exchange's History forum.

It gives several reasons why the Ming Dynasty did exactly what you are proposing.

Here are some of the reasons given:

- They pretty much had all they needed resource-wise in the country,
  trade was not a prerogative and even though Zheng He did go out
  exploring they were not interested in colonies or mercantilism.
- Mercantilism was pretty much frowned upon within the Confucian
  system, merchants did not produce goods they moved them around and
  made money which made them a drain on the system. The few who were
  enterprising and maybe came up with some new product might often find
  themselves in competition from the government
- The Emperor system considered itself the center of the world, the
  focus of the heavens. When outsiders came they gave tribute and
  fealty to the Emperor, so the outside world came to them, they did
  not need to go out
- Belief that China was "perfect" and had everything necessary was
  reinforced by Confucian notions of harmony and society. Signs of
  political and military weakness that appeared near the end of the
  last dynasty were ignored by the emperors and those in the court.

It could be any or all of those reasons.

Other reasons:

- A big bad exists out there (or the fear that one might) and poking
  that hornets nest would end civilization.
- A more highly advanced civilization had a quiet talk with your
  leaders and convinced them that, while they really don't want to
  exterminate humanity, if you cross this line before you grow up, we
  will snuff you.
- The rich (who are in control) don't want other groups finding riches out there and
  competing with them.

Comment: I add that signs of weakness in China were traditionally interpreted as the dynasty failing in its duties, and so losing the Mandate of Heaven.  That is, the system is acting as it should, not failing.

Answer (score 3):

**The renegades**

Once upon a time a bunch of explorers colonized a far planet.
Instead of being patriotic to their mother planet the continued
absence of <strike>propaganda</strike> <strike>indoctrination</strike>
positive thinking led to <strike>normal</strike> pathological
behavior, thinking that they can be *independent* of their mother
planet.

So the mother planet started an <strike>invasion fleet</strike> rescue
mission to get the planet back in line. The colonists decided to fight.
With the new resources of the planet and the experienced mental freedom the colonists were able to launch a nearly successful surprising counteroffensive and they were even able to convince *some ships of the mother planet* to turn their alleigance (**shudder**).

So the home planet has been burned by the experience and for this reason they do not allow anyone to move outside their control again. The betrayal of other ships makes the home planet pathologically suspicious of any contact, so they decided to leave the resources of the new planet alone.

Answer (score 1):

Purported contamination of outer bodies would be the best explanation. Suppose, long time ago some visiting aliens, or this race's own government left a highly dangerous lifeforms (aka the Alien) on other planets of the system. Paying visits there can endanger the whole civilization. And this can be the real reason too, so government can exploit those lifeforms in secret.

Saying that long range space travel is danger in itself probably won't explain the harshness of punishment.

Answer (score 1):

## The government doesn't want to be spread out.

The government feels as if they don't have enough officials/resources to manage and maintain the far away territory.

After the French & Indian war, Britain passed a royal proclamation, saying that no American colonists could settle past the Appalachians. One of the multitude of reasons for this was because Great Britain didn't have enough officials to manage the vast new territory.

If the government feels like it doesn't have enough power, resources, and officials to manage the new territory, it might ban long-term travel to make sure it has no rebellions and therefore competitors.

Answer (score 0):

Religion

There is an ancient holy scripture which is the base of their whole society. It clearly says that the planet and its moons are given to them by their almighty deities, but wandering beyond is a grave sin which will bring terrible damnation to them all. The scriptures were written in an ancient age where they had barely developed metalworking and not the slightest idea of astronomy, but if the holy scriptures were that specific, it must be important.

The government is a theocracy. They take the holy scripture very seriously. Because if people start to disrespect the part which forbids interplanetary travel, they might start disrespecting the part which says that the divine rule of the high priests must not be questioned.

Comment: If God had meant for people to go to other planets we would have been born with reactionless drives.

Answer (score 0):

**Distance**

The group of stars that surround us are at 900 light years of distance from us, with the actual tech available we couldn't find any available planet that could sustain life or any type of self suficient colony.

Even with this restrictions people keep trying; sending to that hellish abysm of nothingness not only our best ships, but our brightest minds too.

This suicide trend took his toll into the billions of our younglings, dreaming in adventures and riches.

The High Counsil almost 3000 years ago in all his wisdom created the "Pierced Veil Law" forbiding any attempt to reach the stars forever.

Answer (score 0):

Such voyages take resources that would be better expended by giving the elite comfortable settings that will enable them to do their best work, and giving the workers a few bones to keep them content -- err, I mean, providing for the poor.

They play up the money they could go to the poor, play down the graft they are cut out on, and ignore as best they can their resentment of anyone's escaping their power by doing things out of their control.  (Some of them aren't even aware of the last motive.)

Answer (score 0):

**

### Clear and present danger.

**

A generation or so ago one random, long range survey team discovered the remains of a recently deceased, technically advanced civilization (albeit perhaps not quite at the level of human civilization). Follow-up government research discovered that the civilization hadn't destroyed itself but instead had been wiped out by an unknown hostile alien civilization that (by default) *was* capable of interstellar travel.

Result? Panic with a capital P at the highest levels of government! Every detail of the discovery is locked down and all those involved sworn to secrecy or otherwise silenced. Research into the event, if it continues at all is done so covertly.

Fearful that release of the news would cause global/interplanetary panic the Government imposes a blackout on the discovery and only the odd rumor leaks out about 'mysterious aliens'. Which the government promptly adulterates by spreading alternate/contradictory 'fake' rumors.

Importantly it also implements a series of policies designed to halt, hinder or make too expensive further expansion. At least until they have a better handle on what humanity is facing. While covert money is diverted to defense R&D and eyes and ears on the border. *The 'enemy' is out there*.